# A word that represents a group of people working to achieve a common goal or dream

Tags: single-word-requests, phrases, idioms, popular-refrains

I am working on a project that involves bringing people together who share common goals or dreams.  Is there a word or phrase to describe groups of people who are working together to accomplish these common aspirations? People have suggested terms like "Dreamers", or "Goal-setters", but I am preferably looking for something a little more catchy.

Or are there any words/phrases that describe a person who accomplishes their goals. Perhaps then, I can then just pluralize that term.

Comment: _Team_ is one such word.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are several words that means a group of people with a common interest/purpose/goal/aim etc. These words might depend on the context as well:

> **[union:](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/union)** a number of persons, states, etc., joined or associated together for some common purpose: *student union; credit union.*
>
> **[coalition:](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/coalition)** an alliance or union between groups, factions, or parties, esp for some temporary and specific reason
>
> **[league:](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/league)** An association of states, organizations, or individuals for common action; an alliance.
>
> **[coterie:](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/coterie)** a small exclusive group of friends or people with common interests; clique
>
> **[association:](http://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/association)** a group of people who have joined together because they have similar interests or aims
>
> **[club:](http://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/club)** an organization for people who have a common interest in a particular activity or subject

---

For the second question:

> **[effector](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/effector)** - one who brings about a result or event; one who accomplishes a purpose

Comment: Thank you very much.  I really like the term coterie and effector.  I will definitely play around with these possibilities.

Answer (score 3):

The name by which they are mostly known in Britain is 'interest groups', i.e.groups pursuing a common interest.

Sometimes these are charities e.g Alzheimers Trust, Cancer Research UK, NSPCC (National Society for Prevention of Cruelty to Children), Save the Children, Oxfam etc.

But included in 'interest groups' are people who campaign on behalf of people who may consider they have suffered a common injustice, such as 'The Liverpool 96', or with a common aim in view e.g. for gay marriage, or against excessive press intrusion of people's private lives etc.

A more informal phrase for 'interest group' is 'pressure group'.

Comment: This is a great answer.

Comment: I got your back, Jack.

Answer (score 1):

People working on developing and using Linux call themselves a Linux community. In France, people using or developing Free, use term "Freenauts" like "astronauts". There is some connotation of union in some form, I guess.
There was an idea of "venture" in a book I read long ago, but it implies pursuing the idea (purpose), gambling even, not achieving it ("nothing ventured, nothing gained")

Comment: I really like the idea of incorporating "naut" as a suffix.  Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

What about *taskforce?* That implies a group with a common goal. Also *club* and *organization* (or *organisation* if you happen to be British) will work.

Answer (score 1):

Why not simply "team"?
Florian

Comment: A good answer will have explanations/reasons/sources. Can you explain why you think "team" is a good choice?